# Можно ли поставить в этом предложении двоеточие вместо тире?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Можно ли поставить в этом предложении двоеточие вместо тире?

"У человека вроде меня, нанавидящего противостояния, отношения с человеком, сколотившим состояние на борьбе и столкновениях, могли сложиться только одним образом (-) мы конфликтовали с самого начала."

Comment: Сознательно или нет, в этой фразе вы описываете пародокс: вы ненавидите противостояния, но конфликтуете с человеком других взглядов.

Comment: Это цитата из книги.

Comment: Проверяете книги на наличие ошибок?

Comment: Нет. Просто напрашивается двоеточие. Поэтому я на всякий случай решил задать вопрос. В современных книгах (последних 10 лет) всё чаще встречается тире. Причём там, где спорный вопрос, всё чаще предпочитают тире двоеточию.

Comment: Да, насколько я знаю, есть такая тенденция.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У человека вроде меня, ненавидящего противостояния, отношения с человеком, сколотившим состояние на борьбе и столкновениях, могли сложиться **только одним образом: мы конфликтовали с самого начала.**

Здесь классическое двоеточие с пояснительным значением, так как нужно раскрыть содержание сочетания "одним образом".

Интонационная (предупредительная, пояснительная) пауза, характерная для двоеточия, тоже на месте, то есть подчеркивается остановка голоса.

Примечание. Повторение корневой основы: противостояние и состояние.

Answer (score 1):

Рекоммендую: [Знаки препинания между частями бессоюзного предложения](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_185).

Между частями сложного бессоюзного предложения нужно поставить двоеточие,

> если после первой части следует пояснение того, о чем идет речь в первой части, например: Напишите план работы: что нужно закупить и подготовить, с чего требуется начать, в какие сроки возможно завершение проекта» или Как все московские ваш батюшка таков: желал бы зятя он с звездами да с чинами (Грибоедов). В эти предложения между частями можно вставить союз А ИМЕННО